# unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a in docker

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm trying to remove all the docker images using the following command:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
```

This fails with the error:

```
C:\Users\Nithi>docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a
See 'docker rmi --help'.
```

This is on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: `$(...)` is **POSIX-family shell** syntax. `cmd.exe` on Windows is not a POSIX-family shell -- if you want one that runs on Windows, look at Cygwin, or msys-bash (also distributed as "git bash", etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's not limited to POSIX-family, `$()` is also supported by PowerShell which is included in Windows, so no need to install a POSIX shell.

Comment: If the OP were running bash, I'd tell them to run `set -x` to enable trace-level logging. No idea what the cmd.exe equivalent is.

Answer (score 9):

You are using the old Windows command line (CMD), which does not support the `$()` syntax. You can run this command in PowerShell instead, which does support the syntax.

To switch to PowerShell, run the command `powershell` in CMD, or search "powershell" in the start menu. You can tell that you're running PowerShell by the prompt now beginning with the letters `PS`.

Answer (score 1):

You must run this command in **PowerShell**,  **CMD** not a POSIX-Family shell.

Comment: PowerShell is not a POSIX-family shell either. It just happens to have similar enough syntax so `$(...)` does the same thing.